# Chartjs populate data with Axios response

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am attempting to have the data on the chart populate based on the set of data the user selects i.e past 24-hours, past week, etc.  I am saving the data and the labels in state.  The labels update according to the selected time frame, but none of the data populates.  I have console logged the data (this.state.data.datasets[0].data[0]) and it is the correct data.

Here is my code:

```
class ChartDemo extends Component {
state = {
        target: 20,
        timeFrame: "past-hours",
        totalSales: [],
        data: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "",
                    backgroundColor: "",
                    // data results
                    data: []
                }
            ]
        },
        chartIsLoaded: false,
    }
getData = (start, end) => {
        API.getData(start, end)
            .then(res =>
                this.setState(state => {
                    // if any sales have occured in selected time period
                    if (res.data[0] !== undefined) {
                        let total = res.data[0].profit.toFixed(2);
                        let totalString = total.toString();
                        const totalSales = state.totalSales.concat(totalString);
                        return {
                            totalSales
                        };
                    } else {
                        // set to zero if no sales
                        const noSale = "0.00";
                        const totalSales = state.totalSales.concat(noSale);
                        return {
                            totalSales
                        };
                    }
                })
            )
            .catch(error => console.log( error));
    }
UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
        this.setTimeFrame();
    }
setTimeFrame() {
const day-one = 2019-08-01;
const day-two = 2019-08-02;
        const timeFrame = this.state.timeFrame;
        this.setState({ target: 20 });
        if (timeFrame === "past-hours") {
            this.getData(day-one, day-two);
            if (this.state.totalSales.length < 8) {
                this.setState({ target: 7, chartIsLoaded: true });
                setTimeout(
                    function () {
                        this.setState(prevState => ({
                            data: {
                                ...prevState.data,
                                labels: [
                                    timeset-one,
                                    timeset-two,
                                    timeset-three,
                                    timeset-four,
                                    timeset-five,
                                    timeset-six,
                                    timeset-seven,
                                    timeset-eight,
                                ],
                                datasets: [{
                                    ...prevState.data.datasets,
                                    label: "24-hour Profit in $",
                                    backgroundColor: "rgb(1,41,95)",
                                    data: [this.state.totalSales]
                                }]
                            }
                        }))
                    }.bind(this), 1000
                )
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removed the [] around this.state.totalSales.  I was essentially putting an array into another array.